# NFTable dynamic denylist not working

Tags: nftables

I'm trying to setup an nftable rule to add source IP if IP tries to connect mulitple times via dport ssh. I'm new to nftables so I'm still trying to understand the proper way of create rules. This rule is on a VPS server. So, I need to lock down access as much as possible.

```
table inet firewall {
    set denylist {
            type ipv4_addr
            flags dynamic,timeout
            timeout 60m
    }

    chain inbound_ipv4 {
            ip saddr @denylist counter packets 9 bytes 540 drop
            ct state vmap { invalid : drop, established : accept, related : accept }
            tcp dport 22 ct state new,untracked counter limit rate over 4/minute add @denylist { ip saddr } accept
            icmp type echo-request limit rate 2/second accept
            tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "allow http"
            tcp dport 443 counter packets 1 bytes 40 accept comment "allow https"
    }

    chain inbound_ipv6 {
    }

    chain inbound {
            type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
            ct state vmap { invalid : drop, established : accept, related : accept }
            iifname "lo" accept
            meta protocol vmap { ip : jump inbound_ipv4, ip6 : jump inbound_ipv6 }
    }

    chain forward {
            type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
    }
```

}